Trying to optimize by bazel tasks in build pipeinline (unit tests primarily) but struggling with a subset of tests that can't run concurrenlty
I have a monorepo that contains many applications. Our code base is organized such that each directory is it's own bazel package (aspirationally), and the unit tests for the corresponding code are as well.
We use the "scala_test" bazel build targets as our codebase is primarily scala (JVM based). We are on Bazel 6 and will likely be a very late adopter to Bazel 7 (probably will start 2nd half of 2025).
Our build pipeline issues a command to "run all tests", which finds hundreds of scala_test targets with there various annotations. Some of our longer running unit test classes are tagged with "exclusive" because they become unbearably flakey when run concurrently but are very stable otherwise. The source of flakiness comes from idiosyncracies of a third party library that we use that is fundamental to the applications.
Since we're on Bazel 6 in addition to paying the penalty for "non-current tests" when using the exclusive tag, we're also paying the penalty of not being able to leverage the remote cache in our build pipeline.
I've been investigating the following options:

Shards (by setting the number of shards to use on each individual scala_test target)
Setting --local_tests_per_jobs in the bazel command (which applies globally, with the idea being to have two steps in my build pipeline where the currently excluseive tests are moved into their own step of the build pipeline and invoked with --local_tests_per_jobs=1 to avoid exclusive tag caching issue

Shards seem like the better option (my understandign is it effectively runs each shard in its own JVM, although I'm not actually distributing the tasks to different machines). However I specify 1 shard in each of my scala_test targets, does bazel use "1 shard" for each target, or does the sharing happen for the tests within the target? If the latter, do I need to define a single target that contains all of my tests?
